# Trouble getting Postfix working on Centos

Tags: php, centos, postfix, sendmail, linux

I'm having problems getting PHP to send mail via Postfix on CentOS Linux 5.6.

I've got Postfix version 2.3.3, which was installed with Yum. I also installed Dovecot as per a tutorial, though I'm not sure whether I need this just to send via SMTP.

When the PHP mail() command runs I get this in **/var/log/maillog**:

```
Aug 22 10:30:57 ade1 postfix[5798]: error: to submit mail, use the Postfix sendmail command
Aug 22 10:30:57 ade1 postfix[5798]: fatal: the postfix command is reserved for the superuser
```

I have Webmin installed, and here's the SMTP settings page: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/618674/_perma/2011-08/webmin-postfix-smtp.png

I entered some config settings changes in **/etc/postfix/main.cf** as per this tutorial:
http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix

In **/etc/php.ini** I have this:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/postfix -t -i
```

Anyone got any ideas about this *"to submit mail, use the Postfix sendmail command"* error?

Would I be better using Sendmail? I was advised that Postfix was simpler!

Cheers :)

Also... (may be related),

**chkconfig --level 345 dovecot on**

returns this:

```
failed to make symlink /etc/rc0.d/K74lvm2-monitor: File exists
failed to make symlink /etc/rc1.d/S26lvm2-monitor: File exists
failed to make symlink /etc/rc2.d/S26lvm2-monitor: File exists
failed to make symlink /etc/rc3.d/S26lvm2-monitor: File exists
failed to make symlink /etc/rc4.d/S26lvm2-monitor: File exists
failed to make symlink /etc/rc5.d/S26lvm2-monitor: File exists
failed to make symlink /etc/rc6.d/K74lvm2-monitor: File exists
failed to make symlink /etc/rc0.d/K35dovecot: File exists
failed to make symlink /etc/rc1.d/K35dovecot: File exists
failed to make symlink /etc/rc2.d/K35dovecot: File exists
failed to make symlink /etc/rc3.d/S65dovecot: File exists
failed to make symlink /etc/rc4.d/S65dovecot: File exists
failed to make symlink /etc/rc5.d/S65dovecot: File exists
failed to make symlink /etc/rc6.d/K35dovecot: File exists
failed to make symlink /etc/rc3.d/S65dovecot: File exists
failed to make symlink /etc/rc4.d/S65dovecot: File exists
failed to make symlink /etc/rc5.d/S65dovecot: File exists
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting confused between Sendmail the software, and `/usr/sbin/sendmail` the standardised interface for sending mail.  Revert your `sendmail_path` back to it's default value and everything will be fine.  Postfix provides a `sendmail`-compatible wrapper that does the right thing about getting mail into the Postfix system.

And, by the way, no, you don't need Dovecot to send mail via SMTP.

Comment: Legend!

Thank you, it's now working perfectly.